# Extra blank column with EPPLUS c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I have a problem when getting data from a gridview and exporting this to a datatable and then using EPPLUS to export the data to Excel. It keeps adding an extra blank column - I cant get it to start at cell A1 see code and image below. Help!
[image]

```
            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Asset_list");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Add the columns to the datatable            
        if (GridView1.HeaderRow != null)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
            }
        }

        //Add each of the data rows to the table
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text.Replace(" ", "");

            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true); 

        pck.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Sample1.xlsx");
        Response.End();
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint before writing the datatable to the spreadhseet (right before `ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);`) and look at the datatable, does it have an extra first column? - My **guess** is that the gridview has a first column you're not accounting for....

Comment: Just realised you are right - The first column in the gridview is the select bit. Just have to work out how not to include that bit?

Comment: Just change your loops to go from 1 instead of 0